# How to get an overlay texture over inline image without extra mark-up using CSS?

Tags: css

I need to give an overlay texture to 100+ images

like this.

[image]

I have transparent `.PNG` texture file. if i use this as `background` then it will go behind the `<img>`. And I don't want to add another `<img>`  or any extra `span`, `div` for texture and `z-index`.

**Is there any other way to achieve it in CSS?**

I need to use specific texture `.png` so i cannot use **CSS gradient** only.

I don't want to use main product image as `background`.

Comment: can you push you code for better understanding

Comment: @sandeep it simple. see example http://jsfiddle.net/cPSFQ/1/ i want to put transparent image over girl's image http://jsfiddle.net/cPSFQ/1/ but without using <img>. I just added transparent image in jsfiddle at bottom to show you.

Comment: I want to achive something like this http://jsfiddle.net/cPSFQ/3/ but i don't want to use the technique i'm using in this fiddle.

Comment: I hope it could be possible using `:after` or `:before` or any other method.

Comment: I don't think `:after` or `:before` are going to work because they insert content IN the tag. But images are self closing tags so they don't work.

Comment: Why in the world are answers that specifically break from the OP's specifications getting posted AND upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're going to have a very hard time getting that texture overlaid on the image without some added element to put it on. If you can't affect the html output, a little javascript would do the trick.

Another option is to place the texture over the top of the other image with absolute positioning. It's hard to know if that's a viable option without more context, however. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cPSFQ/1/.

Answer (score 1):

Glad your post is tagged with CSS3

http://jsfiddle.net/WQTeE/2/

You have to create a reverse mask of the overlay. I tested this in FF9 and Chrome 16

```
img.stockphoto{
    -webkit-mask-box-image: url(http://koivi.com/php-gd-image-watermark/watermarks/Sample-trans.png);
    -o-mask-image: url(http://koivi.com/php-gd-image-watermark/watermarks/Sample-trans.png);
    -moz-mask-image: url(http://koivi.com/php-gd-image-watermark/watermarks/Sample-trans.png);
    mask-image: url(http://koivi.com/php-gd-image-watermark/watermarks/Sample-trans.png);
}
```

Comment: @JitendraVyas - works for me in Chrome 15 and Linux too. Chrome 17 is still in development. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I really do want this answer to work, as I like learning new CSS3 tricks, but maybe I'm missing something.  I retested this on Chrome 18 this morning, tested on iPad, and the android as well.  In all  and in both cases I get something that looks like this:  http://goo.gl/N5u7t however, I was expecting to see something more like this: http://goo.gl/apBtw  It doesn't seem to work at all in IE9 or lower.  (Didn't test on IE10).

Comment: @JitendraVyas you used the `mask-repeat: no-repeat` (and the browser specific prefixes), and not the background-repeat?

Comment: @JitendraVyas - can you provide the actual mask image that you want use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Bs7nv/

In this all I am doing is displaying an image and a div in which we can use the texture image as background and absolute positioning to display over the actual image.

Comment: i know this but don't want to go with this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure css solution to your question that's cross browser compatible. I realize that this answer doesn't meet your original criteria, but I figured I'd supply it anyways so that you could have it as an option.

Using pseudo elements (`:before`) would be a logical choice for CSS3, but alas, they don't work on img tags.

You'll have to do something, rather change the mark-up or add some javascript.  Assuming you can't edit the mark-up (sometimes you can't control your source data), but can control the javascript, you could do it with pure javascript like this:

```
var transparentImage = "http://rd.cas.de/tim/native/image.png";
var imageList = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var arrImages = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++ ) {
   // store the images as is first, otherwise the list is living and
   //  you loop forever...
   arrImages.push(imageList[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < arrImages.length; i++ ) {
   // first wrap all the images in a relative positioned div.
   var wrapper = document.createElement('div'); 
   var newImg = document.createElement("img");
   newImg.setAttribute("src", transparentImage);
   newImg.style.position = "absolute";

   wrapper.appendChild(newImg);
   wrapper.appendChild(arrImages[i].cloneNode(true)); 
   arrImages[i].parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, arrImages[i]);

}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/gqPVb/) that does what you want (but with javascript).